# windows visual studio 2015, C++11 standard, and Armadillo library

Tags: c++11, visual-studio-2015, armadillo

I have a Visual Studio Community 2015 project (x64 Solution Platform) using the Armadillo linear algebra library (version 6.500.5 stable) that receives build errors if I try to use syntax that pulls in C++11. The documentation states that *"When using the C++11 standard, elements in Mat, Col, Row can be set via initialiser lists"*. E.g., if I take the example right from the Armadillo documentation [describing element initialization](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#element_initialisation),

```
// C++11
mat A = { {1, 3, 5},
          {2, 4, 6} };
```

VS2015 generates the error,

```
Error C2440 'initializing': cannot convert from 'initializer list' to 'arma::Mat<double>'
```

In contrast, the C++98 example compiles without error:

```
// C++98
mat A;
A << 1 << 3 << 5 << endr
  << 2 << 4 << 6 << endr;
```

This of course leads me to suspect that C++11 compatibility is inactive, but nowhere in the myriad Visual Studio Project Properties can I locate anything concerning such an option, and results from web searches elsewhere seem to indicate that C++11 compatibility **is** present in versions of Visual Studio from 2012 onward. There are no other problems using Armadillo, and testing the C++11 code under Linux (*gcc 4.9.3*) *does* work fine. Does anyone have any insight into this, or know if there is some hidden C++11 switch for VS2015?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

C++11 support in VS2015 is incomplete. You can forcefully tell Armadillo to use C++11 features by defining [ARMA_USE_CXX11](http://arma.sourceforge.net/docs.html#config_hpp) before including the armadillo header:

```
#define ARMA_USE_CXX11
#include <armadillo>
```

(side note: recent versions of gcc and clang are much better choices for C++11/C++14; you can get gcc for windows from the [MinGW](http://mingw.org/) project).

Comment: That solved it! ... Thank you for the speedy response. Cheers //Rolf